# Inserting values from two different tables into a third empty table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a newbie in PHP, and I have been trying to insert values from two different tables "users" and "avail", via drop-down list, into a third empty table "bookings". Additionally, I also wish to manually insert 2 data "Start_Time" and "End_Time" into the third table. I managed to bring up the form with the submit button.

This is my code(I omitted some parts of the codes at the top):

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Booking form for Carpark </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content ="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" action="bookingssql.php" method="post">

<label type='text'>UserID:</label>
<select name ='UserID'>
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','carpark'); 
$result1 = $conn->query("select UserID from user");
  while($row =$result1->fetch_assoc())
    { ?>
      <option value="<? php echo $row['UserID']; ?>">
      <?php echo $row['UserID']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php
    } ?>

  </select> 
  <br>

<label type='text'> Development:</label>
<select name ='Development'>
<?php 
$conn1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','carpark'); 
$result = $conn1->query("select Development from avail");
  while($row =$result->fetch_assoc())
    { ?>
      <option value="<? php echo $row['Development']; ?>">
      <?php echo $row['Development']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php
      } ?>

  </select>
   <br>

<table border = 3, cellpadding=2,cellspacing=1>
<tr>
<th>Start Time     </th>
<th>End Time     </th>
<th> </th>
</tr>
<td><input type=text name=Start_Time>
<td><input type=text name=End_Time>
<input type=submit value = Book>
</form>

</table>        
</body>
</html>
```

However, the values can't be inserted after i clicked the button, and I am not sure why. This is the remaining code where I think somewhere went wrong here:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','carpark');

$ID = $_POST["UserID"];
$Dev = $_POST["Development"];
$Start=$_POST["Start_Time"];
$End= $_POST["End_Time"];
//Insert Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings (UserID,Development,Start_Time,End_Time) VALUES('$ID','$Dev','$Start','$End')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    $message = "Booking Made!";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    header("refresh:1; url=bookings.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Not Booked";
}



?>
```

Hope I can bring in a fresh new pair of eyes to help me spot my error. Very much thanks in advance!

Comment: My omitted codes at the top were added back in!

Comment: Any Error or Notice ??

Comment: It only tells me "Not booked", which led me to assume that my insert query is wrong, but i just can't figure it out where went wrong

Comment: you must have geting an error, try echo mysqli_error($con); after your query. also remove duplicate mysqli_query from if condition

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UserID']; ?>','','2018-01-26 20:20:20','2018-' at line 1Not Booked

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to the option so try it with:

```
<option name="UserID" value="<?php echo $row['UserID']; ?>
```

and/or:

```
<option name="Development" value="<?php echo $row['Development']; ?>
```